# Extract next x characters from a string following a regex match in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string which somewhere in it contains `Processing date : 14 Aug 2013` or similar.  Its not in the same place every time, so I'm looking at a regex to find the `14 Aug 2013` part.

```
_date = Regex.Match(_headerLines.Last(), @"(Branch processing date : )(\S{1,11})", 
  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[2];
```

Gives me the `14` but not the rest of the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `\S` matches non-space character, it does not work as you expected.

Replace `\S` with `.` which matches any characters (except newline).

```
@"(Branch processing date : )(.{1,11})"
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `\S` matches all character except spaces, so that it will match 1 and 4 and stop at the space immediately after it. You can try:

```
@"(Branch processing date : )(.{1,11})"
```

If you're sure that the date is just after the `Branch processing date :` part, or use something like:

```
@"(Branch processing date : )([0-9]+ [A-Za-z]+ [0-9]{4})"
```

Which is a bit more restrictive.

Comment: @BlueChippy That's because I had more to type xD You're welcome! ^^